# help requires in winavr

Tags: c++, embedded, avr, winavr, avrdude

i am trying to send ---.hex file to my siemens C55 throught serial port but while  doing do i am getting an error

> "make.exe" program
>   avrdude -p atmega8 -P com2 -c stk200    -U flash:w:gsm_remote.hex 
>   avrdude: port name "com2" is neither lpt1/2/3 nor valid number
>   avrdude: can't open device "com2"

avrdude: failed to open parallel port "com2"

make.exe: *** [program] Error 1

please guide me what should i do
the source code is also avaliable at
http://www.4shared.com/file/88235332/4b2370f8/080324-11.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to set the avrdude port on windows (it's described somewhere in the documentation), but I think you're making a bigger mistake here. Siemens C55 (mobile phone, right?) does not run on atmega. It uses Infineon C16X (most probably) like all the siemens phones from 5X/6X series. I don't think this code will work on siemens hardware.

Also Siemens C55 doesn't include the stk200 interface - if you need a flasher for it, look for more information on http://forum.gsmhosting.com/vbb/

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message was

> avrdude: failed to open parallel port "com2"

So do you have a COM2 (serial port) that can be opened? If yes, does it need administrator privileges and you try to run as non administrator?